# RaspberryPi as a passive Man in the Middle

Tags: networking, debian, security

I think about using a Pi to sniff LAN traffic in an fixed environment.

Main problem is that the Pi should not have an IP adress nor being "visible" in the network. I got an second lan interface (USB) and dont know how i can achieve it.

Furthermore it would be nice to get the capture files without too much trouble.

Any approaches? Is there a preffered distro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two ethernet devices (eth0, eth1) you can bridge them like this:

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
brctl addbr bridge0
brctl addif bridge0 eth0
brctl addif bridge0 eth1
ifconfig bridge0 up
```

Now you've got a passive bridge called bridge0 where all traffic send through eth0 and eth1 can be sniffed via wireshark/tcpdump or whatever.. bridge0, eth0 and eth1 got no IP.

If you need an IP you can do this:

```
dhclient bridge0
```

That will assign a IP address to that bridge (most networks got a DHCP server, if not you can assign static IPs too, you even can use a spoofed mac or whatever) - your pi is able to connect to that network to serve e.g. an Apache.

But I would prefer that way: buy a WLAN USB device which is hostapd compatible. plug it and install hostapd to turn your Pi into a wireless router. Now you can sniff eth0, eth1 traffic and if you need the PCAP data you can connect to your raspberry WLAN and get the files via SSH/HTTP or whatever you need..

*I assume that this is only for personal usage or testing issues.*

Any preferred distro? I'd prefer [PwnPi](http://pwnpi.sourceforge.net/)! It is much smaller than [KaliLinux](http://www.kali.org/) or pen-testing distros. Furthermore, I don't need cool looking GUIs, I prefer a simple SSH shell :)

Even X server looks nice on pwnpi:

[image]

Comment: But nmap is not for pcap!

Comment: :P you´r right.. i mean tcpdump, i´ll change that. thx!